# how do I run a downloaded flash object offline?

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject

I saved all the files related to this magazine (in the proper folder structure, which I viewed from my cache): http://www.cbc.ca/heartland/features/mixed-media-magazine/mixed-media-magazine-1

The problem is, the swfobject.js file doesn't open.  I get an error saying 'document' is undefined.  And, when I open individual .swf files such as the page spreads, certain elements work (such as clicking on character profiles), but other elements such as certain backgrounds don't appear.  So, my question is: how can I modify the files I have to get them to interact properly offline like they do online?  If it's too complicated for a simple comment to answer, then any newbie-friendly references I can read up on would be a great help.

Comment: I think you should edit the title of your question to show what you want to accomplish, which is to run a downloaded flash object offline.

Comment: The guys is a beginner.  So he didn't ask the question that he would have if he were an expert.  Take a little time to read the question and you can figure out *exactly* what he is asking.  I believe this question was down-voted and put on hold only because he is a newbie, asking a noob question.

Comment: SO isn't *for* beginners.

Comment: SO is for all skill levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't make one, but you link to a swfobject.js file and then configure it.  I use an automatic code generator.  It's just easier.  I use this online version:  http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/generator/index.html

Also, use the google CDN if you can, then backup with a local version if it's not accessible for some reason.  In practical terms that means putting this in the `<head>` of your document:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script>swfobject || document.write('<script src="js/swfobject.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

The second line checks to see if swfobject is loaded, and if not, loads it from a local source, so make sure that you have a local copy in the src directory path.

Comment: Got a dumb question here: does that generator work when the SWFObject uses multiple .swf files?  I'm not quite sure what the SWF definition should be, and it doesn't seem to give me the option of having more than one.

Comment: You can use the same swfobject.js, but you need to have different embed codes for each flash movie.